# Replacing a form with another form using JQuery together with changing DOM

Tags: jquery, ajax

Assume there are two forms named `profileChange` and `passChange` (in separate files), and there is another page named `update`. By default `profileChange` appears on `update` page in the browser. I use following code for replacing forms:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#pass-change-link').click(function(){
       var link = $(this).attr('href');
       $('#container').load(link);
       return false;
    })
}
```

In this way `passChange` form truly appears in the browser, but I want the changing form also happens on the **DOM**. How to do it?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, when an element is replaced by another element, it's the DOM that has been updated. It seems what you want is event delegation. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the form loaded with JQuery appears in the code(using `Firebug` and etc) in addition the browser.

Comment: Another thing is that after form loads with JQuery the page less your Ajax functionality!

Comment: Is there no any answer?